# Invalid Operation Exception in Asp.Net Web Forms

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i have this code in my page

```
 public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        private String truckID = "";
        private String userID = "";


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            try
            {
                userID = Session["userid"].ToString();
                truckID = Session["truck_ID"].ToString();

                hyperlink_Profile.NavigateUrl = "~/View/Profile.aspx?u=" + userID;
                hyperlink_Inspection.NavigateUrl = "~/View/Inspection.aspx?u=" + truckID;
                hyperlink_MaintenanceChecklist.NavigateUrl = "~/view/maintenanceChecklist.aspx?u=" + truckID; 
                hyperlink_MaintenanceSchedule.NavigateUrl = "~/View/MaintenanceSchedule.aspx?u=" + truckID;
                hyperlink_MaintenanceRecord.NavigateUrl = "~/View/MaintenanceRecord.aspx?u=" + truckID;
                hyperlink_TruckData.NavigateUrl = "~/View/TruckData.aspx?u=" + truckID;
            }
            catch (HttpException ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.ToString());
            }

           MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
           MySqlCommand getRegistration = new MySqlCommand("Select registration_no from trucks where truck_id = " + truckID + "");
           MySqlDataReader setRegistration = getRegistration.ExecuteReader();
           RegistrationNo.Text = setRegistration.ToString();


        }
}
```

I am working with some ASP.Net webforms project and I am receiving an exception error in
`MySqlDataReader setRegistration = getRegistration.ExecuteReader();`

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code`

what could be the possible error of this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You don't open your connection.
2. You don't assign a connection to the command. You can pass it as 2nd argument in the constructor.
3. You call MySqlDataReader.ToString(), which will just return the type name. If you want to get only 1 value from the query just use `ExecuteScalar()`.
4. You don't close your connection. It implements `IDisposable`, you should put it in a `using` statement.
5. You create your query by concatenating strings. It's a terrible practice and a huge security issue. Use parameters.

Comment: Good analysys, but I have already explained the process to him, however the poster doesn't listen and falls from one error to next one.  (Sooner or later its total lacks of acceptance on its previous questions will neglect him also these answers)